# unity combine and detailed different

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm pretty new as a game developer. The company sent a case study, it's okay, but I couldn't find the difference between combine and detailed prefabs, even though I looked on the internet. Anyone have an explanation?

Comment: Can you post some of the scope so we can have context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello **Alienswait** ^^ As far as I know if you are using a detailed prefab, it means that you will have all **sub-objects** in your prefab. For example, imagine you have a house prefab that has a lot of little objects (such as walls, windows, doors...). Although you don't even use the walls in the prefab, these objects and their **TEXTURES** will occupy a place in your **memory** and **CPU**(it will increase batch count). This situation won't be useful for performance. However, if you use a combine prefab (A merged version of the home model), this means that you have only **one object** and **only one texture!** This might save your whole project...